# Interpreting this wikipedia arc length definition

Tags: calculus

In this figure I see an equation where $f(t_{i})-f(t_{i-1})$ is replaced with $\dfrac{f(t_{i})-f(t_{i-1})}{\Delta t}$ then with $f'(t)$. I just know that a derivative $f'(t) = lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{f(t+h)-f(t)}{h}$ so I have to ask - how was that done? The limit in the figure is as $N \rightarrow \infty$ so I tried to replace $lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{f(t+h)-f(t)}{h}$ by $lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{f(t_i)-f(t_{i-1})}{\dfrac{b-a}{N}} = lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{N (f(t_i)-f(t_{i-1}))}{b-a}$ and, that is not equal to $f'(t)$ for me.

[image]

Comment: Let $t := t_{i-1}$, $h := \Delta t$ and notice $t_i = t_{i-1} + \Delta t = t + h$. Then indeed it is just your definition of derivative.

Comment: Also don't forget the $\Delta t$ outside of your black rectangle to make the equality correct.

Comment: Thank you very much !